# Big list of UX techniques

Tags: methodology, usability-engineering

Can anyone point to a big list of UX techniques?

I'd like to build a matrix of those I use, those I don't, along with relative cost estimates.

Comment: Danny, did you ever build this matrix? If there's a public version out there, I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 21):

The Usability Book Of Knowledge has a bunch at [usabilitybok](http://www.usabilitybok.org/methods).

Answer (score 7):

I suggest this three links:

[Quince Ux Patterns](http://quince.infragistics.com/UX-Design-Patterns.aspx)

[Luke Wroblewski Ux Diagrams](http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?156)

[Ui pattern factory](http://uipatternfactory.com/)

Answer (score 7):

[UsabilityNet](http://www.usabilitynet.org/tools/methods.htm) has an interactive methods table, that filters out methods depending on three criteria: Limited time/resources, No direct access to users or Limited skills/experience

Clicking a method takes you through to a page that explains the benefits, outlines the method and points to some further reading on the topic.

Answer (score 6):

The UPA have a great site called the Usability Body of Knowledge. One of the sections is a Methods round up:

http://www.usabilitybok.org/methods

> This section of the BoK presents
>   descriptions of methods, including
>   procedures, resources needed,
>   outcomes, appropriate uses, benefits,
>   and costs. These descriptions will
>   form the core of a knowledgebase that
>   defines our field and will help
>   communicate usability methods to
>   clients, project managers, and team
>   members. Usability practitioners will
>   also benefit from cross-referencing of
>   related methods and pointers to
>   outside resources for more details.

A fantastic resource.

Comment: Apologies - I just saw adrianh's answer... I scanned the answers too quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Dey Alexander has many User Experience design resources on her website [deyalexander.com.au](http://www.deyalexander.com.au/resources/uxd/)

Answer (score 4):

Usability.gov has a great [visual map of ux methods](http://www.usability.gov/methods/process.html) that provides an extensive **step-by-step usability guide of techniques** as well as **several useful related templates**.

You can click any of the items on the visual process map for further information, including detailed definitions and step-by-step how-to's.

Answer (score 4):

Smashing Magazine has a list of [40+ Helpful Resources On User Interface Design Patterns](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/15/40-helpful-resources-on-user-interface-design-patterns/). My favorite is Quince, which makes it fun to explore all the patterns. (can't post link because I'm a new user :( )

Answer (score 4):

Jakob Neilsen shares his thoughts and solutions on Web Usability issues at

[useit alertbox](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/)

I find the information very valuable.

Answer (score 2):

The UXBASIS box is a collection of UX techniques that have been put together to form a comprehensive toolbox.

On the website [www.uxbasis.com](http://www.uxbasis.com) you can see all the techniques it contains, read about them individually and see how they fit together in the overall structure of that which is UXBASIS.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsofts Windows UX Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx). It's mostly for Windows development but many of the ideas that apply across platforms.

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone app of UX techniques has been launched recently - http://www.uxtechniques.com

Answer (score 1):

The UX Mastery collection of UX Techniques is another useful list: http://uxmastery.com/resources/techniques